# What is the claims in ASP .NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Can somebody please explain, what the claim mechanism means in new ASP.NET Identity Core?

As I can see, there is an `AspNetUserLogins` table, which contains `UserId`, `LoginProvider` and `ProviderKey`.

But, I still can't understand or find any information on when data is added to the `AspNetUserClaims` table and what situations this table is used for?

Answer (score 242, accepted):

> what does claim mechanism means in new ASP.NET Identity Core?

There are two common authorization approaches that are based on Role and Claim.

**Role-Based Security**

A user gets assigned to one or more roles through which the user gets access rights.
Also, by assigning a user to a role, the user immediately gets all the access rights defined for that role.

**Claims-Based Security**

A claims-based identity is the set of claims. A claim is a statement that an entity (a user or another application) makes about
itself, it's just a claim. For example a claim list can have the user’s name, user’s e-mail, user’s age, user's authorization for an action.
In role-based Security, a user presents the credentials directly to the application.  In a claims-based
model, the user presents the claims and not the credentials to the application. For a claim to have practical
value, it must come from an entity the application trusts.

Below steps illustrate the sequence of that happens in a claims-based security model:

1. The user requests an action. The relying party (RP) application asks
   for a token.
2. The user presents the credentials to the issuing authority that the RP application trusts.
3. The issuing authority issues a signed token with claims, after authenticating the user’s
   credentials.
4. The user presents the token to the RP application. The application validates the token
   signature, extracts the claims, and based on the claims, either accepts or denies the
   request.

> But, i still can't understand and find any information, when data
>   addes to AspNetUserClaims and what situations this table using for?

When you are in a situation where a Role-Based Security is not used, and you chose to use Claim-Based
Security, you would need to utilize AspNetUserClaims table.
For how to use Claims in ASP.NET Identity, see below link for more information.

http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/12/using-claims-in-aspnet-identity.html

**Update**

> What time i have to use role-based security and when claim-based?
>   Could you please write a few examples?

There isn't a very clear situation where you would or would not use Role-Based or Claim-Based Security, Not like a case where you would use A rather than B.

But, claim-Based access control allows better separation of authorization rules from the core business logic. When authorization rules change, the core business logic remain unaffected. There will be situations where you might prefer using Claim-Based approach.

> Sometimes claims aren't needed. This is an important disclaimer.
>   Companies with a host of internal applications can use Integrated
>   Windows Authentication to achieve many of the benefits provided by
>   claims. Active Directory does a great job of storing user identities,
>   and because Kerberos is a part of Windows, your applications don't
>   have to include much authentication logic. As long as every
>   application you build can use Integrated Windows Authentication, you
>   may have already reached your identity utopia. However, there are many
>   reasons why you might need something other than Windows
>   authentication. You might have web-facing applications that are used
>   by people who don't have accounts in your Windows domain. Another
>   reason might be that your company has merged with another company and
>   you're having trouble authenticating across two Windows forests that
>   don't (and may never) have a trust relationship. Perhaps you want to
>   share identities with another company that has non-.NET Framework
>   applications or you need to share identities between applications
>   running on different platforms (for example, the Macintosh). These are
>   just a few situations in which claims-based identity can be the right
>   choice for you.

For more information, please visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359101.aspx

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i still don't understand, what time i have to use role-based security and when claim-based? Could you please write a few examples?

Comment: @FSou1, there isn't really a case where you would user Role-Based or Claim-Based approach. See my updated answer for more clarity.

Comment: `The user presents the credentials to the issuing authority that the RP application trusts.` What can you use as this authority/issuer? Some examples would be nice. I red the article on the msdn site (the link you provided), but they list only one example: ADFS, are there any other options? Can't find this information anywhere. :(

Comment: For any one looking for real life example, here is good example using driving licence and date of birth. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Simple two lines in above docuemntation cleared many doubts.

Comment: _A Guide to Claims-Based Identity and Access Control_ provides a full explanation of claim vs Role Based Access Control (RBAC)  based approaches. 
The full book is available free and online via MS downloads.

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18868677-a-guide-to-claims-based-identity-and-access-control

Comment: The blogspot link can't be viewed properly with some adblocking  so either remove the "vertical-ads" class on the parent div or disable your adblocker.

Comment: RBAC free Microsoft book mentioned by @ChrisMylonas can be downloaded for free from Microsoft here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28362

Comment: This is a great answer, Particular when Claim-Based security is involving another third party application where authentication models like OAuth are used. When used within same application, claims merely prove `user's authorization for an action`.

Comment: @GauravChauhan your link explains claims really well! Thanks

Answer (score 32):

Just to add more on what @Lin has said above. I am specifically referring to the question:

> What time i have to use role-based security and when claim-based?
> Could you please write a few examples?

I’ve had to add more information to this answer, and this is because I didn’t clearly address the separation between Claim-Based and Role-Based Auth models. From experience and the nature of the concept itself as well presented and documented on Microsoft Docs, the two Authorization models are often used together and an example on when they’re often used together is illustrated on example 3 below. Now let’s discuss the topics in detail:

**Claim-Based Authorization:**

One important thing to note is that Claim-Based authorization is by nature third-party bound as compared to Role-Based one. Claims are pieces of information provided to you (your app) by a third-party application that describes the user. This information can be anything type of data. Let’s make an example:

*Example 1:*

Imagined you have a software app that is used to mix songs. And this app basically uses songs from Spotify or YouTube Music platform etc., but it’s built in such a way that it has full access to those platform’s music library. But this app doesn’t require you to sign in with your Spotify or google account, you basically just register with email and password. But after you’re online, to use music from either Spotify or YoutTube music, you’re asked to enter an email address you used to create your sportify or YouTube music account. And then the app requests (via web services) your subscription account number from that respective third-party app and stores it as a claim. So, every time you try to access the music when you’re online, the app uses the registered claim’s policy to check if you have a subscription account and then allow access. The nice thing about this is that the claims are stored with information such as the Issuer where you store where the claim came from.  And that’s it. You used a claim, subscriotionAccountNumber, provided by a third-party, that describes you on their side. Obviously, this wouldn’t be the best model to go-about this kind of app but it’s good enough as an example. You’re authorizing your user based on some information about them claimed from another third-party application.

**Role-Based Authorization:**

This one here is clear enough. At its simplest, You grant access to users based on their Role and their role only.

*Example 2:*

Imagine an organizational app with multiple users from different positions. You can assign roles to users based on their position and grant access to different information based on their role. Managers, Owners, Employees… Basically not all employees have access to everything Managers and Owners have access to. And this applies to Managers and Owners. Managers are not granted access to some information that only belongs to owners. It’s that simple.

**Putting it all together:**

In applications like ERP systems, Claims and Roles are used together to build up a complex authorization model. I will always say that The current Identity Framework is so complete that often you don’t need unnecessary extensions that disrupt the existing model, Obviously needs may differ and sometimes breaking the model up could be the only option. When Roles and Claims are used together, Claims serve as Permissions. That is why you have the `RoleClaim` and `UserClaim` tables within the model. That is to allow you to extend the authorization beyond the roles themselves.  When claims are used together with Roles, they merely provide access to perform certain actions.

*Example 3:*

Consider a case where you have a clocking system where you have a technician and a manager. At the end of every week, the technician must arrange reports with clocking information showing hours of work artisans worked for that week, which is consolidated and used by payroll. Such systems often must be amended or corrected before final reports are submitted, because you don't want to overpay or underpay your employees. You can use a `Role-Based` approach for the Manager and Technician by creating a `Manager Role` and `Technician Role`. But the `Manager Role` is the one with the ability to access and edit the clocking information of the artisans. On the other hand, you can have the `Technician Role` without these abilities to access that information. But Here's the interesting part; A manager can make a claim and allow a technician to access the Clocking Systems and make reports. So a claim can be made only for access without edit or can be made with access and edit capabilities. Remember, only your app understands what your claims mean. They can be named anything, `GrantWriteAccess`, `GrantReadAccess` etc, there’s nothing limiting you. After having the claims pre-Defined as permissions, all you need to do is to associate that claim with the user. In this case the Technician would have Both `GrantWriteAccess` and  `GrantReadAccess` added to their `UserClaim` table.

This is more like saying, well, By default as the manager I can access some information that my technician can't access. But I am not always around the office? what can I do so that he can still do the work even when I am not around? To solve this the system can have the feature for the managers to create claims(permissions) for people without access to some specific information. We often see these everywhere in our ERP systems. A user without access to some modules and when they get promoted, they're given permission to more modules of the ERP system, sometimes keeping the same user role, and only with some permissions being opened.

Comment: In the role-based approach, each role has one or more permissions and the manager role in your example can be given the permission to grant permissions to other roles so that managers can give technicians certain permissions. All this works in role-based security so it's still not clear to me why we need claims-based security!

Comment: Read carefully @EricMutta, The manager, can give permission to Technician without changing their role. That's where the claims come in. Obviously, there's different roles with different permissions, but what happens if you want to grant a permission to a person without changing their respective role? That's where you use a claim, especially when something is temporary. So in my case, the technicians role isn't changed but they get granted access to the data while keeping their role.

Comment: With some systems you can grant multiple roles, like for example, the technician can further be assigned (Admin) role and have access. But that's if the system is only role based. I find it way better to split permissions as claims because then you make roles very flexible...

Comment: @MosiaThabo Good explanation, but quoting from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-5.0) "When an identity is created it may be assigned one or more claims issued by a trusted party. A claim is a name value pair that **represents what the subject is, not what the subject can do.**"

Comment: @spencer741 That explanation stands mostly when the claim is from an external resource. e.g, imagine you logged in using Facebook via OAuth, the claims will describe you as the subject, not what you can do. But when you use Claims in your application, They can merely be Key-Value pairs that allow you access to the certain resources based on the value provided.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a pretty simple explanation from the [ASP.NET docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-5.0):

> When an identity is created it may be assigned one or more claims issued by a trusted party. **A claim is a name value pair that represents what the subject is, not what the subject can do.** For example, you may have a driver's license, issued by a local driving license authority. Your driver's license has your date of birth on it. In this case the claim name would be DateOfBirth, the claim value would be your date of birth, for example 8th June 1970 and the issuer would be the driving license authority. Claims based authorization, at its simplest, checks the value of a claim and allows access to a resource based upon that value.

It then goes on to give an example that pretty much all of us can understand:

> For example if you want access to a night club the authorization process might be:
> The door security officer would evaluate the value of your date of birth claim and whether they trust the issuer (the driving license authority) before granting you access.

So to answer the question **when should I use claims-based security?**, the answer is **when it's not easy to put people in well defined roles**. For example, in the night club scenario, it's too hard to put customers into roles, so you use claims-based access control based on their age as confirmed by their ID (e.g. a driver's license). However in that same night club scenario you can use role-based security to control who has access to which rooms (e.g. using key cards for "staff only" rooms). Clearly **you can mix claims-based and role-based security** depending on the need.

Answer (score 7):

There are two types of authentication in ASP.Net identity.

1. Role based
2. Claim based

You can either use one of them or both at the same time. Use role based when you have very defined things. For example you create two role teacher and student. Only teacher can add subjects. So you assigned teacher role to those users whose you want to have access to add subjects.

Claim based is more flexible. Suppose you have a requirement some students can also add subjects. In this case you have to create one more role who can be student and access to add subject. But if you are using claim based it would be very easy. Just create claim like addSubject and assign it to any user whise you want to access to add aubject.

Comment: Bad example - `addSubject` is not a claim, that is a permission. Claims are supposed to tell what an identity is, not what it can do.

Comment: @R.V. Come on... Claims can authorize an action and they're very often used for that. That's why there's `RoleClaim` table within the Identity framework. They only often tell what the subject is only if they're from a third party application. Not on the same application. lol!

Comment: @R.V. you can't have a table describing the user and go copy user's details and paste them in claims table and say they describe the user... What would be the purpose of the user table then?

Comment: This answer is good, but it maybe be improved in the direction @R.V. pointed out. I think we could improve it by changing the claim name from `addSubject` into `TeacherAssistant` (though I think both are correct). Or whatever other intruction the user is claiminig about itself. As I read somewhere: "Claims are assertions - they allow the application to trust attributes about a user." For more, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22814023/7389293

Comment: From the previous link: "Claim is what a subject 'is' not what a subject 'can do'. Claims do not replace Roles or Permissions, they are additional pieces of information that one can use to make an Authorization decision."