# Persisting data in Asp.Net MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My application allows our sales team to manage configurations for different clients (ex: email templates, website resources, css..). The client ID is needed on every page of the app to indicate which client is being modified. There is a drop down list in the layout so you can switch between clients.

So far I'm passing around the id on every page, passing it as a query string in my links

```
@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { clientId = Model.ClientId })
```

And having a hidden field in every form containing the client Id.

I didn't want to use sessions, but as the application is growing it's becoming a bit cumbersome to pass client ID in every link, and have a hidden field in every form.

What do you think?

Comment: When the client drop down changes set `ViewBag.ClientID = clientID` and in your controllers check this value.

Comment: By what mechanism is the end user (client) identified and authorized in your application? (I assume the drop down list is used by the administrator.)

Comment: I'm using native forms authentication. All authenticated users can access the dropdown, other actions can require Admin role

Comment: If the drop down list is always in the layout, why don't you get the value from that field? I don't know how you're posting your data back to the server (full post back?, using Web API?, using Ajax?), but you can always get the value from the drop donws list and add it to the posted back data. Why don't you do it this way?

Comment: Most of the time I'm doing a full postback, sometimes ajax. How would you get the value while doing full post back ?

Answer (score 0):

***In ASP.NET MVC*** there are three ways - `ViewData, ViewBag and TempData` to pass data from controller to view and in next request. Like `WebForm`, you can also use `Session` to persist data during a user session. Each of them has its own importance.

- TempData
- ViewData
- ViewBag

[image: Visual representation of three ways]

---

**How to use**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Name = "Monjurul Habib";
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["Name"] = "Monjurul Habib";
    return View();
}
```

***In View:***

```
@ViewBag.Name 
@ViewData["Name"]
```

Comment: Why a down vote? please have the courtesy to comment

Comment: You seem to answer a question about how to pass data from the controller to the view, although that is not what the OP is asking for. Also, TempData is a bad fit for the problem at hand because it is specifically designed to pass data from one request to the next _once_ (it forgets the data as soon as it is read)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Claims instead of passing client Id. For example, as soon as your client is logged in, you set the Client's Id as a Claim (which is actually stored within Cookie). After that, from your Controller's Action Method, you can check the Claim. Here is an example of checking Claim:

```
public static bool HasClaim(string claimType, string claimValue)
{
    ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    return claimsIdentity != null && claimsIdentity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue);
}
```

I think this way would be much easier, maintainable and cleaner solution. I have answered a question about Claim Based Access Control, you can check that here too:

[Role-based access control (RBAC) vs. Claims-based access control (CBAC) in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814023/role-based-access-control-rbac-vs-claims-based-access-control-cbac-in-asp-n/22819885#22819885)

You can create a ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute as

```
 public class ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private readonly string _claimType;
        private readonly string _claimValue;


        public ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute(string claimType, string claimValue)
        {
            this._claimType = claimType;
            this._claimValue = claimValue;
        }

        private static bool IsLoggedIn
        {
            get {
                return HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.User != null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            }
        }

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            if (httpContext == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");

            if (!IsLoggedIn)
                return false;

            return HasClaim(_claimType, _claimValue);
        }
     }
```

And in your Action method, use it as follows:

```
  [ClaimsAuthorize(ClaimTypes.Role, "Your Client Id")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: someone has dwnvoted this answer also..please specify the reason :/

Comment: The client Id has nothing to do with authorization process. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The code I have shown you is just an example about how you could check for Client Id as a Claim. You do not necessarily need to use this code for Authorization, rather, from the Action method, you could call the HasClaim(....,...) method to check the Client Id and execute your Client Specific Logic.

Answer (score 0):

Store the data in the session or set a custom cookie.

One argument for the custom-cookie solution over the session based solution is that there is some overhead involved when ASP.NET has to look up the session and deserialize / serialize the data.

Comment: Don't you think the overhead when using session more or less equals that of "manually" doing the same job if using a cookie? In any case, I would probably go with a cookie too. It also adds the benefit of making it possible to "remember" the choice between sessions, if desired.

Comment: It depends on where you store the session state. If it is stored in-proc, it probably doesn't make that much of a difference, but if you store it in, say, a database or Azure tables, there could be network traffic involved.