# Implementing role-based authorization using .NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, roles

I would like to implement a role-based authorization in my web application that I'm building. The way I imagined to make this is to create 3 tables in my DB like following:

```
1. Roles
2. UserRoles (many to many table)
3. Users
```

After that each user would have a role assigned to him. Now... My question is, How do I permit or forbid access to specific views/controllers inside my .NET MVC application. I've stumbled upon this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "HrAdmin, CanEnterPayroll")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EnterPayroll(string id)
{
    //  . . . Enter some payroll . . . 
}
```

The Authorize property seems to be limiting the specific controllers/actions to specific roles... But what if I read the user roles from the table UserRoles like in my case?? How is my application gonna know what role does the User have on the system ??

Can someone help me out with this ?

Comment: Did you checked out [ASP.NET Identity](https://www.asp.net/identity)?

Comment: You need to add Claims with your roles in your `Login()` method.

Comment: The above is already implemented in the Identity framework built into MVC5. You don't need to worry about creating these tables yourself, just amend the default connection string and point it at a server.

Comment: @SeM aha so basically I shall add the roles into these Claims upon the user login and then do Authorize[...] on my controllers/actions ?? :)

Comment: @User987 yeap, it pretty much everything you need to do.

Comment: If you would like Azure Active Directory and role based authentication ping me - I've been already implementing that.

Comment: @DawidRutkowski Can you show me a practical example on how to implement that ? :)

Comment: @User987 New answer with some example added.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets pretend you have stored your UserName and Roles in Session:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    . . . .

    string userName = (string)Session["UserName"];
    string[] userRoles = (string[])Session["UserRoles"];

    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userName));

    userRoles.ToList().ForEach((role) => identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)));

    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName));

    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(identity);

    . . . .
}
```

Comment: I've tried this method now, but it says that AuthenticationManager class doesn't contains SignIn method for some reason :/

Comment: Add `using Microsoft.Owin.Security` reference

Comment: Here is [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.iauthenticationmanager(v=vs.113).aspx) about `AuthenticationManager` class

Comment: Do you have `Microsoft.Owin`, `Microsoft.Owin.Security`, `Microsoft.Owin.OAuth` in your references?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126911/discussion-between-user987-and-sem).

Comment: private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
        {
            get { return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication; }
        }                         Add this method

Answer (score 1):

if you Authorize a role to access a controller ( at class level ) or a  action ( function level ) they roles will have access. otherwise the access is denied.

if you use just the Authorize keyword without specifying the roles or users, all authenticated users will have access.

hope fully i am making it clear ?

to use claims based identity refer to the following

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee517291.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff359101.aspx

this is on Core

[What is the claims in ASP .NET Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645323/what-is-the-claims-in-asp-net-identity)

Comment: Yep I understand you. The issue here is, how do I add the roles from my DB so that the application knows which role  the user has from the DB. @SeM said I could do it with something called "Claims" ... Is that the right way?

Comment: yes claims based is a way to go , i have modified my repose with some links which can help you

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pieces of code how you can achieve that using Azure Active Directory. Configuring the application in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureApplication(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    ...

    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
    });            

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
        options.ClientId = Configuration.Get<string>("Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId");
        options.Authority = Configuration.Get<string>("Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance") + "Common";
        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            RoleClaimType = "roles"
        };
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnAuthenticationValidated = (context) => Task.FromResult(0),
            OnAuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
            {
               context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
               context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception
               return Task.FromResult(0);
            },
            OnRemoteError = (context) => Task.FromResult(0)
        };
    });

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
       routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Dashboard}/{action=Index}/{id?}");                
    });

    DatabaseInitializer.InitializaDatabaseAsync(app.ApplicationServices).Wait();
}
```

And here is the usage:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin, Worker")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Hello";
    return View();
}
```

and:

```
public ActionResult Submit(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    if (User.IsInRole("SuperAdmin") || User.IsInRole("Worker"))
    {
        ...
    }

    if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    { 
        //do some admin tasks
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tasks");
}
```

Here is my blog post on that: http://www.eidias.com/blog/2016/1/16/using-azure-active-directory-application-roles. You can find there how to configure above roles in AAD.