# User role limit to access some user for showing some pages

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller

I have some clarification to clear MVC user role. I have a page to access some user and as well some user cannot use those pages.So i need to validation user id check whether this user id have access to permission see this page. Can you help me out sort out this issue i want validation.

```
    if (user id =access denied )
    {
       should be retrun error message that user cannot see this page
    }
   else
   {
       should access and show  this page
   }
```

Can you help me

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281330/implementing-role-based-authorization-using-net-mvc-5 ?

Comment: Yes i read,But i could not use....any other simple method....?

Comment: becuase my tech lead said ,use diffrent methid

Comment: MVC filter pipe is good, why your tech lead doesn't let use it?
describe more to help you perfectly

Comment: Please put **all of your constraints** in your question. If your Tech Lead is not going to allow you to use the standard solutions to a problem, we need to know all of those weird constraints up front.

Comment: Don't know i ask y i cannot use this method he said that is complex method use a simple method

Comment: If it is so simple, I'd suggest you ask him or her to assist you with this task.