# aspnet identity tables explained

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Anybody can tell me the purpose of the aspNetUserClaim, AspNetUserRoles and AspNetRoles tables in the identity database that is created by default in mvc?

I could see that AspNetUserLogins is used to store information when users login with 3rd parties login (fb, tweeter, etc..)

Thanks.

Comment: Here's another SO with an explanation of both concepts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645323/what-is-the-claims-in-asp-net-identity

Comment: thanks guys , have a good day